# What is the difference between 'passageway' and 'regular door' links?

Tags: munchkin-quest

In Munchkin Quest, what is the difference between 'passageways' and 'regular doors'? They both cost 1 movement, and I don't think monsters are affected. So, how are they different?

Comment: Are there any monsters that can't open doors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are monsters that can't pass through the doors, Dragon for example. And the Bullrog kicks out the doors and make them a passageway instead.